# Change the default port number for telnet in Linux

Tags: telnet

Hi All i want to change my the default port number for telnet services from 23 to say 2345. I have enabled the iptables rule to accept traffic from 2345 port , but still i am getting connection refused error. I have made following entry ion my iptables.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2345 -J ACCEPT
```

and reloaded the iptables file

Comment: Hi! Can you please [edit] your post to show us the relevant part of any server configuration files you changed?

Comment: changes has been done

Comment: How is you telnetd started? Via `inetd`?

Comment: Did you change the telnet server configuration as well, so that it listens to a non-default port?

Comment: telnet is started via xinetd

Comment: How can i do that

Comment: i have edited /etc/services and assiged 2345 to telnet, but still can't telnet via thay port neither i am getting that port in netstat o/p

Comment: No, don't edit /etc/services, look for `/etc/xinetd.conf` or maybe a file in a direcory called  `/etc/xinetd.d` or something similar.

Comment: Cheers Man, i read the man page for xinetd.d and VOLLA . I got the  answer . 
vi /etc/xinetd
service telnet
{
port 2345
}
 and restarted xinetd service. It worked like for me for port 2345.

Answer (score 1):

I edited `/etc/xinetd.conf`

```
service telnet
{
port 2345
}
#service xinetd restart
```

and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you edit `/etc/services` line:

```
telnet          23/tcp
```

to

```
telnet          2345/tcp
```

and restart telnetd or xinetd or inetd will work for sure.